# Manually logged ELMAH errors aren't sending email

Tags: elmah, elmah.mvc

I'm manually logging certain errors like this:

```
ApplicationException ex = new ApplicationException("Testing");

Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(System.Web.HttpContext.Current).Log(new Elmah.Error(ex));
```

The unhandled exceptions are sending email, but the manually logged ones are not. I've also tried this:

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
```

How do I get these manually logged errors to send email (without throwing and showing a custom error page)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spoke too soon.

This doesn't send email:

```
Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(System.Web.HttpContext.Current).Log(new Elmah.Error(ex));
```

But this does:

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
```